# How to plot multiple equations / solutions on same graph?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

I've been working with physics and I want to plot the potential such that I can have multiple lines that represent multiple potentials. The equation is:
[image]

where V(r) is the potential, and I want to plot many lines so I can see the turning points of the graph. I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so I'm quite clueless. I tried using `DSolve` by differentiating V(r) and asking it to solve, and `ContourPlot` (though I suppose I'd have to turn it into a vector field first, which I don't know how and that was a bit of a random thing I tried). I also tried the normal `Plot`. I got blank graphs. Is it because I have undefined constants that are treated as variables, like *l, M, ε*? I'd really appreciate some help on what code I should use / what to do to have it plot out multiple lines for V(r) that represent the many possible solutions.

Comment: There are many plotting functions in Mathematica, so it depends what you're looking for. I recommend going through the documentation, finding a plot that looks like what you want, and playing around with the "Basic Examples" to understand how they work. Yes, some constants will probably have to be defined. If I have $y = a x^2$, then it cannot be plotted in 2 "dimensions" (colour or other visual cues often act as a "3rd" dimension). However, specific `a` values are easy: `Plot[{1 x^2, 2 x^2, 3 x^2}, {x, 0, 5}]`. Higher-Dl plots can have more unknowns. What should the axes be here? Just V vs r?

Answer (score 2):

You need give some number for your constants, I think that mathematica don´t plot with undefined constants. In this example I did $M=l=\epsilon=1$

```
Plot[{1/(2 r^2), -(1/r^3), -(1/r) + 1/2}, {r, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Or you can put

```
M = 1; \[Epsilon] = 1; l = 1
Plot[{l^2/(2 r^2), -((M*l^2)/r^3), -((M*\[Epsilon])/r) + \[Epsilon]/2}, {r,0,10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

And put the values of the constants that you want in the equalities of the first line

[image]